# Element from array in props vue js

Tags: vue.js

Is it possible from the items array to create a variable item.id (in props)?

```
props: {
 items: {
  type: Array,
  default: () => []
 }
},
```

And layout, just in case

```
<div class = 'bestsellers-item' v-for = '(item, index) in items': key = 'index'>
  <div class = 'bestsellers-item__sticker'>
    <img: src = 'item.img'>
  </div>
  <span> {{item.id}}
</div>
```

Comment: what is your question? You could use the index as id I guess, you would need to do it in the layout though ...

Comment: Props are passed to components. If the item array holds a set of objects, which in case have an object id then you can output the item.id. If your item object does not hold an id then you cannot output an item.id

Comment: @mahatmanich Just wondering if it is possible to use in the methods an item that is in the items array. I need item.id for my function (addCartItem)

Comment: `<button @click="addCartItem(item)">Add to cart</button>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments and also Michal Levý's comment, I think what you are looking for is this:

```
<div class = 'bestsellers-item' v-for = '(item, index) in items': key = 'index'>
  <div class = 'bestsellers-item__sticker'>
    <img: src = 'item.img'>
  </div>
  <button @click="addCartItem(item.id)">Add to cart</button>
</div>
```

And then, your function:

```
addCartItem(itemId) {
    console.log("Do something with item " + itemId);
}
```